# Group By Having Count > 1 in Linq

Tags: linq

I have following data

```
Date          | ProjectTypeID
--------------  -------------
10/31/2016    |     1
11/30/2016    |     2
12/31/2016    |     2
01/01/2016    |     3
```

What would be the Linq query to get all the dates for ProjectTypeIDs which has dates count > 1

Results should yield me following List of Dates because ProjectTypeID = 2 has two dates associated with it

```
11/30/2016
12/31/2016
```

Comment: Added some more information to make my question little clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(item => item.ProjectTypeID, item => item.Date)
                 .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                 .SelectMany(group => group)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting compile time error on .SelectMany(group => group, item => item.Date)                 var parentDates = parentObj.GroupBy(c => c.ProjectTypeId)
                                        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                        .SelectMany(group => group, item => item.EndDate)
                                        .ToList();

Comment: my bad .. I didn't test it. You can try the updated version